# Nutch 2.x not crawling websites like flipkart and jabong

Tags: hbase, hdfs, nutch, web-crawler

I've done some experiments with nutch to crawl websites which were not having any ajax calls and I got all the data.

I executed following steps to get the data.

1. user@localhost:~/sample/nutch/runtime/local/bin$ ./nutch inject /path/to/the/seed.txt
2. $: ./nutch generate -batchId 321
3. $: ./nutch fetch 321
4. $: ./nutch parse 321
5. $: ./nutch updatedb

I have hbase as the storage which stores files on hdfs. If I execute these 5 steps it gives me all the data if the url is http://www.naaptol.com/brands/nokia/mobile-phones.html but if I change it to http://www.flipkart.com/mens-footwear/shoes/sports-shoes/pr?sid=osp,cil,nit,1cu&otracker=hp_nmenu_sub_men_0_Sports%20Shoes it gives me nothing

My nutch-site.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>storage.data.store.class</name>
                <value>org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore</value>
                <description>Default class for storing data</description>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>http.agent.name</name>
                <value>com.datametica.agent</value>
                <description>this is just an agent name</description>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>http.robots.agents</name>
                <value>datametica_robot</value>
                <description>this is just a robot</description>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>plugin.folders</name>
                <value>/home/sachin/source_codes/svn/nutch/nutch_2.x/build/plugins</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex-urlfilter blocks urls that have querystring parameters:

## skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.

-[?*!@=]

Modify that file so that urls with querystring parameters are crawled:

## skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.

-[*!@]

Nutch probably lacks the support for crawling Ajax page. See [this](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/How-to-crowl-AJAX-populated-pages-td3783398.html)

you can probably look at
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1323

Comment: thanks man it works but i have one more problem when i am running nutch it is getting the data but not html in case of http://www.flipkart.com/mens-footwear/shoes/sports-shoes/pr?sid=osp,cil,nit,1cu&otracker=hp_nmenu_sub_men_0_Sports%20Shoes but it gives me html content in case of http://www.naaptol.com/brands/nokia/mobile-phones.html let me know if you know something.

Comment: Sachin, You must accept the answer given by others. You can ask as many question as you want. But it will good if you give some credit to those who have already answered your questions....